# Have I to put spring-mvc.jar in my classpath to create a Spring MVC project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am pretty new in Spring. If I want to implement a Spring MVC project have I to explicitly put the **spring-mvc.jar** file into my classpath? From what I know the Spring MVC project is not part of the Spring Core.

Is it right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go many ways but I'll suggest you to learn a build automation tool like maven or gradle. It will take care of everything related to dependency management. Here's a good resource to get started https://spring.io/guides/gs/gradle/

Comment: Yes I know that I can use Maven, mine was more a theorical question...I want know if the spring-mvc.jar file is a separate project from the Spring core project and if it is putted into the classpath when a Spring MVC project is created (manually or using Maven(

Comment: Yes you are correct. You'll have to put dependencies related to spring MVC in your classpath. Spring MVC doesn't come with spring core.